# How to change project's java version in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I reinstalled java on my laptop with different version, and after that, my project can't run well in Intellij Idea. So I want to know how to change project's java version in Intellij Idea?

Comment: "Can't run well" or "Can't compile"?  The former is a symptom of a weaker CPU (e.g. like one a laptop would have).  The latter is a symptom of a Java version issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> File | Project Structure

Add your new SDKS, and chose right sdk for your Project.

Comment: That doesnt work you didnt even check the modules

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure that the compiler correctly chose the version:

   You need to go to Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler and update the **Target bytecode version**

   Easier: press `Shift` twice and type *Java Compiler* and will lead you to that.
2. Setup the project SDK
   Go to Project Structure > Project > Project SDK and add the link to the local Java file
   [image: Capture]

Comment: Those options dont exist